# Can I connect a MWBC to a tandem breaker and would it need a handle tie?

Tags: electrical

[image]I have a 12/3 MWBC feeding one single bedroom that is about 8x14 in size. It feeds two lights and approximately 5 outlets. In the panel, each leg was on a 20 amp single pole breaker, one on top of the other. Needing to make some space in the panel (allows 48 circuits), I added some tandem breakers and placed this MWBC on a 15 amp tandem.

Are MWBC permitted on a tandem breaker? If so, does it need a breaker tie? Should I just replace it with two separate single poles breakers (the way it was) and add a breaker tie? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @AlK Most likely, you cannot use a tandem for an MWBC. Most tandems end up with each half on the same “leg” of your service (as opposed to opposite legs with a full-size two-pole breaker) meaning you could overload the shared neutral’s limit by a factor of two (30A on 15A wiring, etc). There may exist some single-space breakers that do attach to both poles and would be safe for MWBC use, but they are rare. Post the make of your panel, photos of all its labeling, and the make/model of the breaker you are considering using.

Comment: I added the only photos it would allow me to. This is a Homeline 100amp main breaker panel being used as a sub panel. Model of the panel is, HOM2448M100PCVP. The breaker that is being used is, Homeline 2-15 Amp Single-Pole Tandem Circuit Breaker. Considering this line only feeds 2 lights /

Comment: 5 outlets, is on a tandem 15amp breaker now, rather than a 20amp and is for a bedroom, do you believe the neutral can still have an issue?

Comment: You definitely **MUST NOT** put a MWBC on that breaker - you risk overloading the (totally unprotected) neutral by a factor of two. If one side is really only lighting you could probably put it on the same breaker as the receptacles and be safe without breaker trips (especially if the lights are LED).

Comment: Thank you. Can I remove the tandem, add two single pole 15’s and place a break tie? I still have space in the panel to accommodate this change. This would place each breaker on different phases of the panel

Comment: Yes, two separate single-pole 15A breakers handle-tied would be fine. A two-pole 15A breaker would also work (HOM215) for a lower price than two HOM115s and a handle tie, and without the potential hassle of actually locating handle ties.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Make sure you install a GFCI receptacle as the first one in the string of receptacles in a bathroom! Oh, you can't do that _simply_ on a MWBC-  there are tricks to make it happen. Loads of questions here about that already, do a search.

Comment: The two hot wires MUST MUST MUST be [on opposite poles!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4)  There MUST be 240V between them!  They cannot go on ONE tandem because there would be 0V between them, overloading the neutral.  ***However, a MWBC can be installed between two tandem breakers (2 breakers 4 throws, MWBC on the inner throws). They make special handle-ties for that***.  It can also be on the inner poles of a [quadplex](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/110151) or the outers if they are handle-tied.

Comment: In fact it is impossible to (legally) handle-tie the two throws of one tandem, because no approved products exist to do that.  There's no reason to ever do that.  So the handle-ties "keep you honest" as it were. The handle-tie for between two tandems I believe is the HOMTHTCP. Home Depot shows it, three for $7.